# Using ArcPy to add layer to map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers

I am having trouble adding my result to the current map using ArcPy. I keep getting this error problem, "ValueError."

Here is my script:

```
Result = arcpy.analysis.Clip('FeatureClipped','ClippingFeature','FC_clip')
type(Result)
<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>
m.addLayer(Result[0])
ValueError: Result path
```

Answer (score 5):

You have used one argument in the addLayer() method which would indicate you are using the ArcGIS Pro flavour of ArcPy so I will assume this is the case.

If you read the help file on the [Clip tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm) its output is a *Feature Class*.

Now continue to read the help file on the [addLayer()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) method on map, it says its input must be a *Layer or LayerFile*, neither of which are a Feature Class.

So that is why you get the error.

Look one row up in the table of methods for map and you see addDataFromPath(), this will add a Feature Class as a layer to your map. Here is an example snippet.

```
result = arcpy.analysis.Clip('rivers', 'ISLANDS',r"c:\scratch\fcClipped.shp")
layer = result.getOutput(0)
m.addDataFromPath(layer)
```

You  could also have used the Make Feature Layer tool.